# Good idea to symlink a virus database directory?

Tags: symlink

My Comodo Antivirus is installed in /opt/Comodo where its virus databases are stored in a directory `/opt/Comodo/scanners` which by far is the largest sized directory. I am running Crunchbang (debian) from 60gb SSD where `/` is allocated 16gb /swap 2gb & the rest as NTFS named 'CRUNCH'.

Now what I did:

```
sudo mv /opt/Comodo/scanners /media/CRUNCH/Misc/Comodo_Bases/scanners
sudo ln -s /media/CRUNCH/Misc/Comodo_Bases/scanners /opt/Comodo/scanners
```

Above is an attempt to move & then symlink whole database directory from NTFS partition in a bid to save space while the executables remain where they are in `/opt/Comodo`.

Will my solution work?

**UPDATE**
IT WORKED

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue with doing this. Seems like a reasonable approach to consolidate files. The only issue you might run into is if the piece that updates the virus databases has issues with writing through the link and/or if it has issues writing to the files through the NTFS driver, but otherwise seems fine.